# Live Streaming Android (http or httplive)

Tags: android, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

IS there anybody have run http live Streaming(discovered by Apple) on android device. I have some of Streaming Url. like "" www.abc/iphone/france24/allegro/fr/f24_fr.m3u8 "" type. My task is to make a app for android 3.0 OS type mobile.  Can anybody help me to make it.

The topic is new in android market.So that there is not much help on internet. I have got one of sample code to run livestreaming on android device.but it doesnt run urls that i have. these url are effectively working on IPAD or IPHONE.  Thanks

Comment: I have solved the problem. Actually i replace http protocol to httplive  protocol. And its work well.

Comment: Could you please further explain it? I really need to solve this issue. I have 3gp video and use vlc to stream it: cvlc -vvv dancing-skeleton.3gp --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=128.0.0.6:9090/jlanza}' In my android I set the videoview source to http:// and to httplive:// but nothing is displayed.

Comment: httplive is only run above 3.0 OS in android.I think you have to check video streaming on device.May emulator is playing video very late.

Comment: @Rana.S, can you please provide this as an answer?

Comment: Switching http with httplive didn't work for me on a G-N (Galaxy Nexus) with Android 4.1.1. I created an Intent with action ACTION_VIEW. I set the data to 'httplive://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8'. I requested to start activity with this intent and got an exception that 'No Activity found to handle Intent'.

Answer (score 2):

check out the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17118) in android bug report. replacing http with httplive worked for me. 
Here is the sample code below from the bug report

```
private void playVideo(Integer Media) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {
        switch (Media) {
            case Globals.TEST_HTTP:
                path = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";
                break;
            case Globals.TEST_HTTPLIVE:
                path = "httplive://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";
                break;
        }
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```